# Google Sheets column A into an external website via a select list

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have attempted to modify the code I found for a dropdown onclick list and make it into an HTML Select list with options.  The only issue is I only get a single entry.

My end goal is to have country1, country2, country3 so the user selects a country and that selection is added via the external website into the google sheet.

Name (data entry)
Email (data entry)
Course (choose from select list on sheet1)

submit (adds all entries into google sheet2)

The data entry submit is simple but allowing a user to select from a list and that selected option being added into sheet 2 is stumping me.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Post to Google Sheet Demo</title>

  <!-- bootstrap & fontawesome css -->

  <link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fontawesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />



  <!-- BootstrapValidator CSS -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.0/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css"/>



  <!-- jQuery and Bootstrap JS -->

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



  <!-- BootstrapValidator JS -->

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.0/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>

  

  <!-- Animated Loading Icon -->

  <style type="text/css">

  .glyphicon-refresh-animate {

      -animation: spin .7s infinite linear;

      -webkit-animation: spin2 .7s infinite linear;

  }



  @-webkit-keyframes spin2 {

      from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}

      to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}

  }



  @keyframes spin {

      from { transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);}

      to { transform: scale(1) rotate(360deg);}

  }

  </style>
  
  
  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    
    
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  
</head>



<body>
    
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(ValIDS);

function ValIDS() {
  var queryValIDS = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18HxssOQ5GJarg9tx0DIfuBqPdQTl5jj-h7_G_3vFIl4/edit?usp=sharing');
  queryValIDS.send(handleQueryValIDResponse);
}

function handleQueryValIDResponse(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in ID Validation Query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }

  var datatable = response.getDataTable();
  


for (var i = 0; i < datatable.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    var ddItem = document.getElementById('myDropdown').appendChild(document.createElement('A'));
    ddItem.href = '#';
    var ddItemContent = ddItem.appendChild(document.createElement('SPAN'));
    ddItemContent.id = 'cat' + (i + 1);
    ddItemContent.innerHTML = datatable.getValue(i, 0);
  }

  

}

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById('myDropdown').classList.toggle('show');
}






function schedule(selectedValue) {
  {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content');
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>




<div class="dropdown">
    
   <select onchange="schedule(this.value)">
   <option id="myDropdown"></option>
   </select>

      
      
  </div>
</div>  

    
    
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my code for the select which does not work, can you assist. Sorry I am not a coder by nature.

Comment: After this line `var datatable = response.getDataTable();` do this line `console.log(datatable.getNumberOfRows())` and see what you get in browser console to make sure you actually get data. Then we can proceed to debug.

Answer (score 0):

And change respective code to this. See you can see sheet data in dropdown.

```
// for loop
var html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < datatable.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
  html += '<option>' + datatable.getValue(i, 0) + '</option>';
}
document.getElementById('myDropdown').innerHTML = html;

// dropdown
<select onchange="schedule(this.value)"  id="myDropdown">
</select>
```